# The Following Classes could not be instantiated. with admob

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

here is my xml code for admob 
every thing work fine before adding ads but now it crashes the app, force closed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"

android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sidney">
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="here is my ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my build.gradle code

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 17


}


}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile files ('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```

i also put GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in libs folder of my project.

this is my Mainfest.xml with activity AdActivity

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

it shows Rendering Problem The Following Classes could not be instantiated. in view section and when i run this on emulator or my android mobile phone it crashed, showing force close... please help thanx in advance

Comment: Post the logcat showing the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the warning, when i run the app its load very fine and show admob ads accurately,